# How to create this border styles in HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css, border, css-tables

I am desperately searching for the right code to create table borders in HTML/CSS for my website looking like on this image:

[image]

I couldn't find a way to do this...

here another picture:

[image]

It looks like the cell have some "3d effect" or something like this....

Comment: Wow... Use basic CSS, I recommend going to learn CSS a little before posting here.

Comment: Ok thanks. I did, dont worry. But havent found a way to create this gaps between the bordercells. Maybe the image was bad. Here another: http://i.imgur.com/3dGv3Th.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is a sample (Note that Samples are not complete answers and so my answer is) ,see this, Learn CSS basics

The following code will give you the result you want though.

```
 //HTML
    <table style="border:none;">
  <tr>
    <td>Corporate Finance</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Derivatives</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Economics</td>
  </tr>
</table>

// CSS
    table {
      border-spacing: 5px;
}

table, th, td {
    margin-top:2px;
    border-left: 1px solid #E8E8E8;
    border-bottom:2px solid #E8E8E8;
    border-right:1px solid #E8E8E8;
    margin-top:2px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so far. I am not sure if your code create this "gaps" at the corners of the cell. Its difficult to see them, but I would like to use them... http://i.imgur.com/3dGv3Th.png

Comment: See [here](https://jsfiddle.net/nepal12/mspyroaq/)  , And if you carefully read my answer, I have clearly written, that answer will  not be 100% but will be in the similar way. Try playing around with CSS Basics man.. See http://www.textfixer.com/tutorials/css-tables.php

Answer (score 0):

you can use it in different way. but you have to learn basic CSS.

```css
.borderall td{border:1px solid #ccc;}

.borderbottom td{border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;}
```

```html
table 1
<table width="100%" class="borderall">
<tr>
  <td>block one</td>
    <td>block one</td>
    <td>block one</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br/>
table 2
<table width="100%" class="borderall">
<tr>
  <td>block one</td>
</tr>
  <tr>
  <td>block one</td>
</tr>
  <tr>
  <td>block one</td>
</tr>
</table>
<br/>
table3
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="borderbottom">
<tr>
  <td>block one</td>
</tr>
  <tr>
  <td>block one</td>
</tr>
  <tr>
  <td>block one</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks so far. I am not sure if your code create this "gaps" at the corners of the cell. Its difficult to see them, but I would like to use them... i.imgur.com/3dGv3Th.png